# Protobuf-net: Recommended way to precompile Dictionary<string, CustomClass>

Tags: protobuf-net

I am currently using the below code to deserialize data.

```
using (var zipData = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
{
    data = Serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, CustomClass>>(zipData);
}
```

Custom class has many nested custom objects inside it. I would like to pre-compile this. What is the recommended way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not at a PC right now - did you try it? Did you get any issues? Actually, the first thing to try is making a parent/wrapper object that **has** a dictionary. For complex reasons, that is much simpler for it to process.

Comment: I tried this and it worked wonderfully. I used the wrapper and compiled the dll. For our use case our deserialization times dropped from an average of 28 seconds to 20 seconds. If I remove the outliers the average drops from 25 seconds to 18 seconds. I am looking forward to seeing the improvements in serialization times.

Comment: If you have a specific example I can look at to optimise, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should *just work*, even when pre-compiled - as long as the `CustomClass` has suitable `[ProtoContract]` etc attributes so that the `precompile.exe` tool knows what to do. You can help it a little more by using a single root object:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SomeWrapper {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<string, CustomClass> Items {get;set;}
}
```

But this isn't essential, and as it happens the output of a list/dictionary/etc as the root object is **100% identical** to the output of a wrapper object with a list/dictionary/etc as the 1st member (`[ProtoMember(1)]`).

To precompile, use [`precompile.exe`](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html) from the google-code download:

```
precompile YourApp\Your.dll –o:YourSerializer.dll –t:YourSerializer
```

Then the application-level code becomes:

```
using (var zipData = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
{
    var serializer = new YourSerializer();
    data = (SomeWrapper)serializer.Deserialize(
        zipData, null, typeof(SomeWrapper));
}
```